# Communication with electric and bluetooth wheel (imortor)

Tags: wheels, electric-bike, dynamo, electronics

I would like to know about the specs, standard or protocols to communicate through Bluetooth with the controller embedded in the wheel.

By default the wheel can be managed through BT with a very poor Android/iphone app.

- Control driver – FOC (field-oriented control) intelligent drive controller
- Smartphone Connectivity – Bluetooth 4.0 and USB for charging.

Specs/info is very poor and reduce to above lines

Is there any standard/protocol for this type of hub controllers?

[image: imortor kit]

Answer (score 1):

Is it using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, aka Bluetooth Smart)?

There are some standardized BLE profiles for things like Heart Rate or Speed and Cadence. There are BLE Scanner apps for your smartphone which can show you what kind of profiles a device implements. It’s possible that some features are exposed as standard profiles (and can then be used by e.g. bike computer apps (or stand alone bike computers) which support those sensors). Unfortunately things like configuration or firmware update will be implemented with a custom profile which you’d have to reverse engineer to find out what is actually transmitted.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy#Sports_and_fitness_profiles